# onsubmit in jsfiddle not working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am trying to use `onsubmit` to call a function in javascript but it is not working. I have tried looking similar questions but nothing worked. I have also tried `onclick` with the submit button, that too doesn't seem to work.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return add();" name='contact'>
```

I want this to work with pure JS, not jquery.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/una2jrgf/3/).

Comment: Select No Wrap - in <body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default fiddler adds the script in a onload handler as given below, so all the functions/variables created in the script will be inside the scope of the onload handler. When you use the inline event handler the script will look for the method in the global scope where the method won't be found

```
window.onload = function(){
    //our script here
}
```

so in the left panel under Frameworks & Extensions in second select box select `No Wrap - In body` or `No Wrap - In Head`

Comment: Can you please see why is the form still submitting, even after the function being called and returning false. I have also tried `return false` at the end of the function.

Comment: Oh sorry. There was a different error. Thanks for all the help.