# Failed to validate email address with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

I would like to run my page to test out whether my validation works. However, it does not work with email address. I have added regular expression for email address. It doesn't validate fully.

I entered `a@live` without typing `.com` it able to accept it. I assume this is because i type `input="email"` Correct me wrong. Is it due to the wrong regular expression or maybe the way I placed my code?

**javascript**

```
function validate(){
     var fname =  document.getElementById('fname').value;
         var lname =  document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var email =  document.getElementById('email').value;
         var emailReg = '/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/';
    var re = /^[\w ]+$/;
         var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

     if(email=="")
     {
        alert('Please fill in email fields');   
        return false;
     } 
 else if(fname=="")
     {
        alert('Please fill in first name fields');  
        return false;
     } 
     else if(lname=="")
     {
        alert('Please fill in last name fields');   
        return false;
     } 
     return true;
}
```

**register.php**

```
    <form name="registrationForm" method="post" id="registrationForm" class="registrationForm" action="processRegister.php" onclick="validate">
        <div class='input1'>
            <span id="emailAddress-label" class="help"></span> 
              <input class="regemailaddr" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address " value="" required>
        </div>
          <br> 
            <span id="fname-label" style="margin-bottom:" class="help"></span>
                <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name " class="fname" value="" required>
            <span id="lname-label" class="help"></span> <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name " class="lname" value="<?php echo $user_profile["lname"]; ?>" required> 
          <br>
               <button class="greybtn" type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
                <button class="cancelbtn" type="button" id="cancelButton" onclick="window.location='#';return false;">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `live` is a valid hostname, and `a@live` is a perfectly valid email ?

Comment: where are you testing the input against the regex?

Comment: i tried to just type this in the form and click the submit button, it accept.That why I confused how come it can accept since i didnt enter email with correct format.

Comment: sorry i don't understand you @user2181397

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript also the answer given by Eric J. you need to test your input

Comment: Where in the validate() function are you testing the value from the input field 'email' agains the regular expression? The regular expression itself look alright.

Comment: it is not possible to validate every input in one function? like what i did above @MartinStaufcik

Comment: Are you sure that 2 to 4 characters is sufficient for [top level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)?

Comment: i not sure. what is best that I can implement for top level domains? @RobG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a regular expression

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
```

but you do not test against it

```
var isEmail = emailReg.test(email);
```

Comment: i should test it in the function validate() ?

Comment: Your validate() function is not being called at all in the fiddle.  Try putting an alert('called'); as the first line in validate().  Also you don't actually check isValid in your if...else if... logic.  You need to do that.  There are some issues with making fiddle work with onsubmit.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750369/onsubmit-in-jsfiddle-not-working